# Establish a write-watch on already committed pages

Tags: winapi

With VirutalAlloc() you can specify MEM_WRITE_WATCH. Is it possible to establish a write watch after allocation on pages that were previously committed without MEM_WRITE_WATCH ?

Comment: What specific action do you want to perform? I still don't quite understand, another way to monitor the allocation page?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT: The purpose doesn't matter. I just want to subsequently set a write-watch on previously committed pages and I have good reasons for that.